# No Cordova event is working other than deviceReady event

Tags: android, cordova, events

I'm trying to capture device events in my Android Cordova app. But, except the `deviceReady` event , no other event is getting fired. I'm using the event as given in the Cordova documentation after the deviceReady event. My Cordova version `6.4.0`

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {

  document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
    // My Code here
  });

  document.addEventListener("volumedownbutton", onVolumeDownKeyDown, false);

  function onVolumeDownKeyDown() {
     console.log('volume downn')
    // Handle the volume down button
  }

  document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);

  function onMenuKeyDown() {
   console.log('menu button')
      // Handle the back button
  }

  document.addEventListener("volumeupbutton", onVolumeUpKeyDown, false);

  function onVolumeUpKeyDown() {
    console.log('volume up button')
     // Handle the volume up button
  }
};
```

Comment: Are these event-handlers defined within the deviceready-function or outside it? As it is shown [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/de/latest/cordova/events/events.backbutton.html#vollst%C3%A4ndiges-beispiel) for the backbutton-event.

Comment: @Blauharley They are defined after the deviceReady event is triggered as given in that link.

Comment: You inserted code is ok, nevertheless there is still code missing that calls this code too early. How did you wrap these handlers?

Comment: Please check my updated code. That is how I am calling those events.

Comment: I've already your your code within my deviceready-function and it worked with me. This code is defined somewhere too early.

Comment: You mean I should define them before the deviceReady event too ?

Comment: Can anyone help me debug this issue please ?

Comment: @suzo this is the code i m using and it works. function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackButton, false);    
} function onBackButton(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.notification.confirm("Are you sure you want to exit ?", onConfirm, "Confirmation", "Yes,No");
}

Comment: @Gandhi : Thanks for that,  I too used the same code, but it's not working for me. Not only backbutton, but no event is working except deviceReady.

Comment: @suzo can you post your complete code. Cos in some other question also you have raised the same concern but that uses angular. I m able to make it work in my vanilla cordova project.

Comment: @Gandhi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41315616/android-cordova-backbutton-event-not-triggering , Code in that question is exactly how I'm using.

Comment: As @Blauharley said, your function is calls this code too early, just add timeout into different listeners with minimum of 1 second time

Comment: @suzo try calling deviceready event listener inside document ready function

Comment: @suzo i suggest you to look at this sample -https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_InAppBrowser This may not be relevant to you but the project did use backbutton event and its a tested sample. This should help

Comment: @KirankumarDafda: I've already tried timeout too, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

See one question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255319/cordova-ajax-request-pending-for-ever) where updating cordova version to `6.4.0` was giving an error into same project which was working fine with version `6.2.0`

And the solution was to downgrade the version of cordova helped him to recover the project again.

I have created one test project and putted this `index.html` which working perfect for me, just try adding the same into your test project and let us if this is working or not

My Cordova version `6.2.0`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="cordova.js"></script> 
        <script>
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            function onDeviceReady(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    try{
                        document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(e){    
                            alert("Back Button Clicked")
                        }, false);
                    }catch(e){
                        alert(e);
                    }
                }, 500);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Click Android Back button to see event fired or not</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```